# How can I create a android app from laravel web application?

Tags: android, laravel, web-applications, mobile-application

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to create an android app based from the laravel web application? I don't know where to start, and give me some suggestions for creating a mobile app?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you make it with procedural php?

Comment: put your site on a webview or develop api for mobile.............

Comment: @user2736704, I have some tools to create an android application but, I need more resources on how it works?

Comment: @this.esty, I like to have a webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is good for server side application but isn't made for the front-end application so I suggest you to choose another way to develop your app.

If you do want to stick with web technology, try to use PhoneGap which use HTML5 and Javascript to develop application.

Comment: Is there some sources on how to make the first app in phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a business process already done and want to use that in you native android app, you can create a REST interface to that laravel business process. So you don't have to throw it away and start from scratch.

Using REST interface to your server code will make it universally accessible to any app that use web connection for data fetching.

You can create an SPA using HTML5, javascript and bootstrap css - a single page application that is responsive and running in mobile browser that connect to your laravel REST function or you can develop a native app using android studio, phonegap or any native android dev and still can connect to your laravel through the REST interface.